# Using android views in opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-view

I have a view made in openGL. I want to include some android view in it. Is there is any way we can use android view in openGL. For Example: I have a ListView which i want to transform using OpenGL APIs.

Note: I know we can use android animation classes to animate listview, but i want to club my openGL view.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two options

1. Render view to bitmap (using view.getDrawingCache()), use bitmap as an openGL texture
2. Emulate the view in openGL using shapes and an orthogonal camera (a lot of work)

In case 1, it may be slow to keep a realtime update of the screen. You are best off trying to use Android's animation tools and creating custom views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Using any of above option, i will loose events in view.